# how to unmap a network driver when a user logs out of my vb6.0 project software?

Tags: networking, vb6

this Code will map my PC to a Network drive within the LAN that my PC is connected to. now what i want is to undo the mapping that this code does.

can you provide any sample code/suggestion?

```
Dim WshNetwork As Object
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Y:", "\\172.16.11.240\pmva_dtr"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RemoveNetworkDrive](https://ss64.com/vb/removenetworkdrive.html):

```
WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "Y:"
```